# toCharArray returns different result between Android 4.3 and previous Android SDKs

Tags: java, android, utf-8, arrays

The result of the string method toCharArray for the code below is 2 in Android 4.3, and others return 1, does anybody know why?

```
    byte[] SECRET_BYTES = {(byte) 0xfc, (byte) 0xbc};

    Log.i("string", "SECRET_BYTES - " + SECRET_BYTES.length);
    String txtPwd = new String(SECRET_BYTES, "UTF-8");
    char[] charsPwd = txtPwd.toCharArray();

    Log.i("string", "length of charsPwd - " + charsPwd.length);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The byte sequence `FCBC` does not form valid characters in UTF-8:

- `FC` is an invalid start byte because its 6 highest bits are set, when 4 is the maximum allowed.
- `BC` is an unexpected continuation byte; it isn't preceded by a valid start byte.

I'm not sure if it should be considered two invalid characters or just one; you can argue in favor of both cases. You probably should not depend on this behavior in any way.

Comment: thanks, but the result is same even the start byte is not FC, such as byte[] SECRET_BYTES = { (byte) 0x2d, (byte) 0x1c, (byte) 0x69,
    (byte) 0xb0, (byte) 0x27, (byte) 0x46, (byte) 0x32,
    (byte) 0x6a, (byte) 0xbc, (byte) 0x1, (byte) 0x30, (byte) 0x1c,
    (byte) 0x29, (byte) 0xfc, (byte) 0xbc };

Comment: What do you mean by the result being the same? Those bytes encode valid characters until `B0`, which is not valid because it's a continuation byte without a start byte, then again valid characters until `BC`, another continuation byte without a start byte, and so on... So decoding that sequence will give you some valid characters.

Comment: I have put the following code that seems working identical between 4.3 and previous SDK, do you know whay?Charset cs = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
  ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes.length);
  bb.put(bytes);
  bb.flip();
  CharBuffer cb = cs.decode(bb);

Comment: They must have changed the implementation. How malformed characters are handled is not documented anywhere with this level of precision, so they can change it on a whim. You should not depend on whether a sequence of bytes with invalid UTF-8 is decoded into one or several replacement characters. (What are you trying to do anyway? The bytes don't encode UTF-8 text, so decoding them to characters doesn't make much sense.)

Comment: I am trying to convert a byte array to a char array for comparing purpose, the original byte array was getting from somewhere else which I cannot change, so I just want to seek for a reliable solution to convert it to be a char array

Comment: What do you want to compare with the byte array? Is it another byte array?

Comment: we use this byte array to do HMAC checksum in order to ensure the data integrity, but the key generation algorithm we used only accept char array, so we have to convert this random generated byte array to be a char array. and use the same key to calculate the hmac value for the content, and compare this hmac value between server and Android client. this way was working well until Android 4.3, guess Android 4.3 have made some change on UTF-8 decode on invalid bytes.

Comment: In that case, why don't you generate random characters instead of bytes, or change the algorithm to accept an array of bytes, or at least use an encoding where each byte sequence maps to a unique string (ISO-8859-1 for example)? Not being able to tell the difference between the byte sequences `#8899` and `#AABB` may even be a security problem in your case.